# Python3: Calling a class as a separate process

Tags: python-3.x, class, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am playing around with the Process library from multiprocessing and I was trying to call a class from another file as a separate process, however, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

and it still exists in the same process as my stdout is this:

```
20472 __main__
20472 CALL
internal func call
Leaving Call
Process Process-1:
#This is where the error prints out
Leaving main
```

where 20472 is the pid.

Main File:

```
import CALL
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(os.getpid(),__name__)
    p = Process(target=(CALL.Call(),))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print("Leaving main")

import os
```

Call Class File:

```
class Call():

    def __init__(self):
        print(os.getpid(), __name__)
        self.internal()

    def __exit__(self):
        print("Leaving Call")

    def internal(self):
        print("internal func call")
        self.__exit__()
```

Comment: As the message says, the `target` kwarg to `multiprocessing.Process` should be a callable. Is there a specific reason you put an extra tuple there? Try `p = Process(target=CALL.Call)`.

Comment: @Jeronimo - that solved my problem! Thank you! Late night and tired coding thinking target was the args parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comments by @Jeronimo - changing

```
p = Process(target=(call.Call(),)
```

to

```
p = Process(target=(call.Call))
```

was the solution giving the correct output:

```
2965 __main__
2966 CALL
internal func call
Leaving Call
Leaving main
```

with a separate process for the called class.